# Zend 1 Redirect to controller from library

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
$this->_helper->redirector('save', 'index', 'report', $params);
```

This does not work when i use it from a library file It says

> Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Mylib::getHelper().

But When used from controller it works properly.
Can any guide me with code what I need to do?

Comment: Can you give specific details, what exactly fails when it "does not work"?

Comment: @lessthanideal added it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really try to do this kinda thing from a controller, but I've found a use-case for this in a library file as well, so there's no shame in it :-)

```
$redirector = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector();
$redirector->gotoSimpleAndExit($action, $controller, $module, $params);
```

More info here http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.9/Zend_Controller/Zend_Controller_Action_Helper/Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector.html

Comment: @SwapnilShende Not a problem

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to execute the redirect from your library, I would suggest that you modify your library function/s to return a result of some kind to the controller and then handle the redirect from the controller based on that result.